# Same Query taking more time to fetch less records and less time for fetching more records

Tags: sql-server

I have a Query which takes more time when fetching fewer records but less time when fetching more records.

Query fetching more records :-

```
SELECT Orders.OrderId, Orders.Action, OrderKey,_orderKeys.CustomerKey,
      _orderKeys.Source, Orders.OrderStatusId, ErrorCode, ErrorDescription,  
       ServiceProviderID, ReprocessCount, EffectiveDate, CreateDate, LastModifiedDate, 
        SourceName,OrderStatus.StatusName as OrderStatusName,OrderXML 

FROM dbo.OrdersArchive Orders WITH(NOLOCK) JOIN dbo.OrderKeys _orderKeys WITH(NOLOCK) 
ON _orderKeys.OrderId = Orders.OrderId 
JOIN dbo.OrderStatus WITH(NOLOCK) 
ON OrderStatus.OrderStatusId = Orders.OrderStatusID 
WHERE SERVICEPROVIDERID = 1 
AND CREATEDATE >= '01/21/2013 15:27:00' 
AND CREATEDATE <= '01/23/2014 15:27:00' 
AND (Orders.OrderID LIKE '%' AND _orderKeys.OrderKey LIKE '%') 
AND _orderKeys.CustomerKey LIKE '4289581' 
AND _orderKeys.Source LIKE '%' 
ORDER BY CreateDate
```

Query fetching less number of records :-

```
SELECT Orders.OrderId, Orders.Action, OrderKey,_orderKeys.CustomerKey
       ,_orderKeys.Source, Orders.OrderStatusId, ErrorCode, ErrorDescription
       , ServiceProviderID, ReprocessCount, EffectiveDate, CreateDate
       , LastModifiedDate, SourceName, OrderStatus.StatusName as OrderStatusName
       ,OrderXML 
FROM dbo.OrdersArchive Orders WITH(NOLOCK) JOIN dbo.OrderKeys _orderKeys WITH(NOLOCK) 
ON _orderKeys.OrderId = Orders.OrderId JOIN dbo.OrderStatus WITH(NOLOCK) 
ON OrderStatus.OrderStatusId = Orders.OrderStatusID 
WHERE SERVICEPROVIDERID = 1 
AND CREATEDATE >= '2014/01/21 15:27:00' 
AND CREATEDATE <= '2014/01/23 15:27:00' 
AND (Orders.OrderID LIKE '%' AND _orderKeys.OrderKey LIKE '%') 
AND _orderKeys.CustomerKey LIKE '4289581' 
AND _orderKeys.Source LIKE '%' 
ORDER BY CreateDate
```

If you see , query is much faster when i select records for 1 year but is slow when i select records for only 2 days. Can someone please assist as to why am i seeing a difference in execution time

Thanks

Comment: The first thing I notice is that your date formats are different.  The first is `m/d/Y` but the second is `Y/m/d`, so most likely one of them isn't returning what you expect.  Have you looked at the results to verify?

Comment: HI - Result was the same even when i used the same date format

Comment: @user3225648 . . . You need to look at the execution plans for the two queries.  SQL Server has a cost-based optimizer.  It is probably making different choices in the two cases.

Comment: what is Orders.OrderID LIKE '%' (and other similar conditions) supposed to do?

Comment: @PrfctByDsgn - I use these queries in an application...if i dont specify any value from the application , then query would look like this Orders.OrderID LIKE '%' stating "all Orders.OrderID values"

Comment: if you want all orders without filtering on the OrderId you should just leave out that condition ... reducing the number of conditions will probably improve the performance of your query ... check the query plan to verify the effect

Comment: @Gordon :- Execution plans seem to be different, but am unable to make out as why a difference in execution plan

Comment: @user3225648 . . . The difference is because SQL Server says in one case something like "oh, I estimate 10 rows from this data, so I'll do a nested loop join" and in the other "oh, I estimate 10,000 rows so I'll do a hash join".  In my experience, nested loop joins are the culprit in performance on complicated queries.  Fixing the statistics might work, but I wouldn't bet on that.

Comment: @Gordona : Am not god at analysing statistics. Can you please help me as what needs to be checked and how can it be fixed. Please provide any relevant links to know more aboutstatistics

Comment: Try to stick different `OPTION` on your query to see if it will behave better. Try `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` and later `OPTION(MAXDOP 1)` sometimes execution plan goes crazy unless you specify `MAXDOP 1`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff updating statistices certainly helped fixing the problem. Thanks for your help